# Smoothing out a list

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

You should write a program or function which takes a non-negative integer `k` and a sorted integer list `L`as input and outputs or returns a smoothed list `M`.

`M` is created from the ascending list `L` by inserting at most `k` integer elements while keeping the list sorted. The inserted integers should be chosen in a way that the maximum forward difference of `M` will be as small as possible. We will call this smallest value "smoothness".

The forward differences of the list `-1 3 8 11 15` are `4 5 3 4` and the maximum forward difference is `5`.

With `2` insertions the smoothness of `2 10 15` is `4` and a possible output is `2 6 10 11 15` with forward differences `4 4 1 4`.

### Input

- A non-negative integer `k`.
- An ascending integer list `L` with at least 2 elements.

### Output

- The ascending integer list `M`.
- If multiple correct answers exists output exactly one of them (any one is sufficient).
- **Your solution has to solve any example test case under a minute** on my computer (I will only test close cases. I have a below-average PC.).

### Examples

Input (`k`, `L`) => A possible output and the maximum forward difference (which is not part of the output) in parentheses

```
0, 10 20 => 10 20 (10)

2, 1 10 => 1 4 7 10 (3)

2, 2 10 15 => 2 6 10 11 15 (4)

3, 2 10 15 => 2 5 8 10 12 15 (3)

5, 1 21 46 => 1 8 15 21 27 33 39 46 (7)

5, 10 20 25 33 => 10 14 18 20 24 25 29 33 (4)

3, 4 4 6 9 11 11 15 16 25 28 36 37 51 61 => 4 4 6 9 11 11 15 16 22 25 28 36 37 45 51 59 61 (8)

15, 156 888 2015 => 156 269 382 495 608 721 834 888 1001 1114 1227 1340 1453 1566 1679 1792 1905 2015 (113)

8, -399 -35 -13 56 157 => -399 -347 -295 -243 -191 -139 -87 -35 -13 39 56 108 157 (52)

5, 3 3 3 => 3 3 3 3 (0)
```

This is code-golf so the shortest entry wins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
S+Qu?smt%hHrFdC,QtQ>GvzGhvz
```

Input given like:

```
3
[2, 10, 15]
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%2BQu%3Fsmt%25hHrFdC%2CQtQ%3EGvzGhvz&input=3%0A%5B2%2C+10%2C+15%5D&debug=0) [Test harness.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FZ.z%3DQmvd-cechcZ%22%3D%3E%22%5C%2Cdk%3DzhcZ%5C%2C%0AS%2BQu%3Fsmt%25hHrFdC%2CQtQ%3EGvzGhvz&input=%22%22%0A%22%22%0A0%2C+10+20+%3D%3E+10+20+(10)%0A2%2C+1+10+%3D%3E+1+4+7+10+(3)%0A2%2C+2+10+15+%3D%3E+2+6+10+11+15+(4)%0A3%2C+2+10+15+%3D%3E+2+5+8+10+12+15+(3)%0A5%2C+1+21+46+%3D%3E+1+8+15+21+27+33+39+46+(7)%0A5%2C+10+20+25+33+%3D%3E+10+14+18+20+24+25+29+33+(4)%0A3%2C+4+4+6+9+11+11+15+16+25+28+36+37+51+61+%3D%3E+4+4+6+9+11+11+15+16+22+25+28+36+37+45+51+59+61+(8)%0A15%2C+156+888+2015+%3D%3E+156+269+382+495+608+721+834+888+1001+1114+1227+1340+1453+1566+1679+1792+1905+2015+(113)%0A8%2C+-399+-35+-13+56+157+%3D%3E+-399+-347+-295+-243+-191+-139+-87+-35+-13+39+56+108+157+(52)%0A5%2C+3+3+3+%3D%3E+3+3+3+3+(0)&debug=0)

Note: At the time the question was asked, there was a small bug in Pyth related to using `rFd` inside `u`, which I just fixed. The bug rendered it impossible to ever use `F` inside `u`, which was definitely not intended.

```
S+Qu?smt%hHrFdC,QtQ>GvzGhvz

                               Implicit:
                               z is the number of insertions, in string form.
                               Q is the input list.
              C,QtQ            Pairs of elements, e.g. [(2, 10), (10, 15)]
           rFd                 d = (a, b) -> range(a, b)
        %hH                    Take every H+1th element of that range
       t                       And throw out the first one.
      m                        Perform this process for each element pair
     s                         And combine the results into one list.

                               The above is a minimal set of additional elements
                               To reduce the maximal difference to H+1.

  u                     hvz    Repeat until the result stops changing, where
                               the prior result is G, H starts at 0 and
                               increases by 1 each repetition, and
                               G is initialized to eval(z)+1.
   ?               >GvzG       If not G[eval(z):], return G. In other words,
                               if the prior result was short enough, stop.
                               Also, this is always false on the initial call.
    smt%hHrFdC,QtQ             Otherwise, recalculate with H incremented.
S+Q                            Take the result, add the original list, and sort.
```

---

Here's a version which would have worked with the interpreter at the time the question was asked. It's 28 bytes, and works exactly the same way:

```
S+Qu?smt%hHr.udC,QtQ>GvzGhvz
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%2BQu%3Fsmt%25hHr.udC%2CQtQ%3EGvzGhvz&input=3%0A%5B2%2C%2010%2C%2015%5D)

[Git commit of the appropriate version, f6b40e62](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/f6b40e62fd77048f8b3e5b6a8c0e970086fa9e91)

Comment: I never thought of using `rF<seq>` to unpack two-element tuples.

Comment: @orlp It's a great trick, and I've used it way back in the day when `u` worked differently and `e` didn't exist, `urGHd` was shorter than `rhd@d1`. I'll put it on the Pyth tricks page.

Comment: You can shave off a character, you don't need the `U`.

Comment: @orlp Thanks. Actually, `yvz` fails when `vz = 0`, but `hvz` does the trick.

Comment: As the code wouldn't work with the Pyth version which was available when the question was asked I chose not to accept this solution. If you give an answer which doesn't rely on the bugfix, ping me and I will accept it.

Comment: @randomra Added a solution that works on the interpreter that existed when the question was asked.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 104

```python
def f(L,k,d=1):
 M=[];p=L[0]
 for x in L:M+=range(p+d,x,d);p=x
 return M[k:]and f(L,k,d+1)or sorted(L+M)
```

Tries different maximum increments `d`, starting from 1 and counting up. Fills in gaps of each pair `(p,x)` of successive elements by taking every `d`'th number in the gap. If `M` is longer than the quota allows, recurses to try a higher `d`. Otherwise, returns a list of the added and original elements, sorted.

This does all the test cases without delay on my machine.

Comment: Did you try something like 1, 1000000000?

Comment: @edc65 That would take this algorithm really, really long, but I run of stack depth way before that.